# how to use URL of upload featured image in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

in wordpress I am creating a theme but I need a help,

```
<? the_post_thumbnail();?>
```

when I do that it gives me the entire `<img src=#>.....`

everything is fine so far but I want to do something like

```
<a href="UPLOADEDIMAGEURL"><? the_post_thumbnail();?></a>
```

Hence,
I need to take uploaded Image URL and wrap it with anchors then replace the uploaded image url how can I do that ?  I have tried some in jQuery but I think I can also do that from php also ?

Here is the jQuery version (for that I couldnt take the img src attribute and replace to a href.)

```
$('.floatedImg').find('img').wrap( "<a href='#' class='colorbox'></a>" );
```

Solution 1 : can be handled via jQuery
Solution 2 : can be via php

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$img_url = wp_get_attachment_img_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'thumbnail');
?>
<a href="<?php echo $img_url[0]; ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail();?></a>
```

For reference:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src

Answer (score 0):

You can put someething like this in your *functions.php* file

```
function get_thumbnail_url() {
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_img_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'thumbnail');
        return $thumb_url[0];    
    }
    else {
        return get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/images/thumbnail-default.jpg';
    }
}
```

and then

```
<a href="<?php echo get_thumbnail_url(); ?>"><? the_post_thumbnail();?></a>
```